# OSPF into BGP Redistribution issue

Tags: cisco, redistribution

[image]I am having trouble with basic OSPF redistribution into BGP. BGP peers between R10 and R12 are up.

I have full connectivity between Area 0. R10 0/0 is also in that area. I cannot get BGP routes from R10->R12  to redistribute into my OSPF area.

If I put a `default-information originate always` statement in (quad 0's) this will allow connectivity.

I created R28 and was able to get RIP E2 routes into the OSPF, so I am not crazy. R6 shows the E2 route from RIP is getting in. I have tried every method of BGP redistribution (e.g. subnets, connected, metric, etc.). Thoughts greatly appreciated!!

R10 routing configuration:

```
R10#sh run | sec router
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 redistribute bgp 65000 subnets
 redistribute rip subnets
router rip
 version 2
 redistribute ospf 1 metric 0
 network 172.0.0.0
 no auto-summary
router bgp 65000
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 redistribute ospf 1
 neighbor 15.1.1.2 remote-as 65000
 no auto-summary

R10#
```

R6 routing table:

```
R6#sh ip route

     3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       3.3.3.3 [110/3] via 78.33.28.1, 03:56:04, FastEthernet0/1
     6.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       6.6.6.6 is directly connected, Loopback0
     172.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O E2 172.0.0.0 [110/20] via 78.33.44.2, 00:08:54, FastEthernet1/0
     78.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 8 subnets
C       78.33.44.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
O       78.33.38.0 [110/4] via 78.33.28.1, 02:20:11, FastEthernet0/1
O       78.33.34.0 [110/4] via 78.33.28.1, 02:20:12, FastEthernet0/1
C       78.33.32.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
O       78.33.13.0 [110/3] via 78.33.28.1, 03:56:06, FastEthernet0/1
O       78.33.30.0 [110/3] via 78.33.28.1, 03:56:06, FastEthernet0/1
C       78.33.28.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
O       78.33.24.0 [110/2] via 78.33.28.1, 03:56:07, FastEthernet0/1
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think BGP is not advertising the OSPF routes? Remember that OSPF has a lower AD than iBGP, so the routing table will show OSPF routes over iBGP routes.

Comment: Because 15.1.1.x is not being propagated on R6 within the OSPF area. The route is not being sent so the routers cannot find R12.

Comment: Can you post the output of show ip bgp?  Are you sure that route is in the BGP table?

Comment: You are not using OSPF to advertise the `15.1.1.0` network. You would need a network statement in OSPF to advertise that network.

Comment: !!!!! Success rate is 100 percent (5/5)

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I needed! Thanks Ron for a great answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your network, you are redistributing `172.0.0.0` from RIP into OSPF, and you are not originating any routes in OSPF. You are then redistributing OSPF into iBGP, but the original RIP route is being seen in the other router through OSPF, not iBGP. That would be normal because OSPF has an AD of 110, but iBGP has an AD of 200. Basically, R6 trusts any routes received from OSPF mare than the same routes received from iBGP, so the OSPF routes get installed into its routing table instead of the iBGP routes.

Comment: Thank you for the input Ron. I am redistributing bgp 65000, which is the AS for 15.1.1.2 , (R12) . My goal is to create reachability  from OSPF-0 to BGP-65000 and vice-versa.

Comment: You simply are not advertising the `15.1.1.0` network in any of your routing protocols. You don't have any network statements in RIP, OSPF, or BGP to advertise that network, so none of the routing protocols will advertise it.